# Moving cells in Excel 2013 is slow compared to Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am using Excel 2013 with a simple workbook. It contains ~30 sheets, and ~80 rows and ~20 columns per sheet, filled with numbers, and the sum of the rows of one sheet is used as the first cell of the column in the next sheet.

If I open the file freshly and move a cell within a sheet, Excel 2013 takes about 30s to do the task, where Excel 2007, with the same file and the same cell to move does it instantly.

I already disabled the animations and checked the graphics card, which were causes for some Excel 2013 performance issues.

How can I speed things up in Excel 2013?

Comment: Have you turned off auto calculations?  I find this is usually the biggest issue with slow workbooks.  I don't have excel 2013 so I can't do any comparisons.

Comment: I just did, it had no effect on the performance. With manual calculation, it also takes 30-45s to move a cell.

Comment: Another observation: cut and past has the same effect like moving the cell (which I expected), but delete the source cell and type the value into the target cell works instantly.

Comment: try this link this might help you https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/07/11/disable-animation-excel-2013/

Comment: I experience the very same problem. Tried [all that](https://superuser.com/questions/699372/moving-cells-in-excel-2013-is-slow-compared-to-excel-2007#comment1095509_699372) and also playing with sheet protection and no success.

Answer (score 1):

When I encounter weird performance problems, I try the following in VBA, then preforming the action.

You also might have problems with your blank cells.  Select the cells you think should be blank and go to Home>Editing>Clear>ClearAll.

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False`

Hope this helps